# Python - update value in the list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list, it stored user_id and the balance of their 3 accounts.

```
my_list= [
{'user': 1000, 'account1': 100, 'account2': 200, 'account3': 100},
{'user': 1001, 'account1': 110, 'account2': 100, 'account3': 250},
{'user': 1002, 'account1': 220, 'account2': 200, 'account3': 100},
]
```

If a user(user: 1001) want to add 100 to his account2, how can I update only the related value?

I know how to update 1 dictionary like this...

```
update_value = 100
dict["account2"] += update_value
```

I also know how to loop through a list like this...

```
for d in my_list
......
```

However, how can I loop through the list and choose the related dict(by user_id) and update it?

(I'm using python3.4)

Comment: You should consider storing your users in a more convenient format, like a dict with the user id as the keys: `{1000: {'account1': 100, 'account2': 200, 'account3': 100}, 1001: {'account1': 110, 'account2': 100, 'account3': 250}, ...}`

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm new to python, I just created a simple dict to store my data. Your suggestion is good, it seems more reasonable than my existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the following

```
for each in my_list:
     if each['user'] == "1001" #or you can use a variable here
        each['account1']+=100 # even here, instead of account1 you can use a variable
```

The above code works because its the reference you are updating.

Comment: Your code is simple! I considered some solutions which are too complicated...  I have updated my celery cronjob with your solution, and it is working without problem now!

Answer (score 1):

Combine what you know.

**Steps**:

1. Iterate through list.
2. Update item corresponding to the required user.

**Code**:

```
for x in my_list:
    if x['user'] == 1001:
        x.update({'account2': x['account2']+100})
```